# object takes no parameters

Tags: python, typeerror, magic-methods

I'm getting the above error when I run the following code:

```
class Song(object):
    def _init_(self,lyrics):
        self.lyrics=lyrics

happy_bday = Song([ "happy birthday to you.",
                    "i don't want to get sued.",
                    "so i will stop right here."])
```

When I run it from PowerShell I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "qa.py", line 12, in <module>
    "so i will stop right here".])
TypeError:object() takes no parameters
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `init` method needs 2 `_` on either side, not just 1

```
def __init__(self, lyrics):
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your source code again.  There's a discrepancy between the error message and your source.  Your source says:

```
"so i will stop right here."])
```

but your error message says:

```
"so i will stop right here".])
```

A period outside instead of inside the quotes matters quite a bit!